# How to display modal after submitting form?

Tags: javascript, php, modal-dialog

I'm trying to display modal right after submitting a form. 
Here's my code inside php tag (checks if user checked a box and if so, it is supposed to display the values of the row checked in a modal- but my modal isn't working..it only works if I make another button outside the button to display it.. ):

```
if(isset($_REQUEST["submit"])) {
    if(isset( $_REQUEST["userSelection"])) {
        $check= $_REQUEST["userSelection"];
    }
    if($check==0) {
        echo "walay sulod";
        // var_dump($check);
    } else
        $a = implode(",",$check);

    $_SESSION["userSelection"] = $a;
    // var_dump($_SESSION["userSelection"]);
?>
<script type="text/javascript"> 
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#exampleModalCenter').modal('show');
    });
</script>
<?php
}

?>
```

Here's my table containing a checkbox in each row:

```
<form method="REQUEST" action="" id="formID" name="userCheck">
    <div class="margin_table">
        <table class="table table-bordered table-hover">
            <thead>
                <th>School name</th>
                <th>Location</th>
                <th>Population</th>
                <th>Cost</th>
                <th>TNotchers</th>
                <th>Rating</th>
                <th><input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit" class="btn btn-primary render" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModalCenter"></th>
                <!-- <th><input type="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModalCenter"></input></th> -->
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <?php foreach ($school as $s) {
                    echo '<tr>';
                    echo '<td>'.$s['school_name'].'</td>'; 
                    echo '<td>'.$s['location'].'</td>';
                    echo '<td>'.$s['population'].'</td>';
                    echo '<td>'.$s['cost'].'</td>';
                    echo '<td>'.$s['topnotchers'].'</td>';
                    echo '<td>'.$s['rating'].'</td>';
                    echo '<td><input type="checkbox" name="userSelection[]" id="mymod" onclick="userSelection()" value="'.$s['school_id'].'"</td>';
                    echo '</tr>';
                }
                ?>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
</form>
```

Here's my modal:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="exampleModalCenter" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalCenterTitle" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLongTitle">Modal title</h5>
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                </button>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <?php var_dump($_SESSION["userSelection"]); ?> 
                    ...
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I hope you could help me out. Thank you.

Comment: where did you add the `$(document).ready` part ? the php form isn't complete.

Comment: what do you mean php form isn't complete? I'm sorry.

Comment: here `?>` this part does not have an opening tag

Comment: did you consider using `onsubmit()` as shown [here](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onsubmit.asp), or do you prefer firing the modal in back end for some purpose?

Comment: Or you can use `$.ajax({    type: "POST", .... success: function (data) { $('#exampleModalCenter .modal-body').html(data); $('#exampleModalCenter').modal('show');}` dependently how is your data jsonified.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to show the modal once a checkbox is checked use:

```
echo '<td><input type="checkbox" name="userSelection[]" id="mymod" onclick="$(\'#exampleModalCenter .modal-body\').html(\''. $s['school_id'] .'\');userSelection();" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModalCenter" value="'.$s['school_id'].'"</td>';
```

Or even fittier add `$('#exampleModalCenter').modal('show');` in the function `userSelection()`

If yo want to submit the form at checkbox click add this `$("[name=submit]").click()` in your `onclick()` method.

This would show checked value from the backend side, which is safer.

You may also add arguments to a custom function added at `onsubmit()` to tell the server if the form is sumbitted or not yet.